# I made everything right but firebase functions not working

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have followed these steps one by one to apply firebase functions

1- I connected to my firebase with android studio and connect to cloud messaging and installed the Dependencies

2- I installed firebase tools via terminal and logged in ( it didn't work first time until I wrote this code)

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

3- I wrote in my terminal `firebase init` and then choose my project and javascript, then yes to install npm

4- I made sure that my index.js is inside the functions folder

5- I wrote this code in sublime text to test the notification

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
```

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite(event =>{

        const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;
        const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

        console.log('We have a notification to send to : ',  receiver_id);

        if(!event.data.val()){
            return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ',notification_id);
        }

        const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/deviceToken`).once('value');

        return deviceToken.then(result =>{
            const token_id = result.val();
            const payload = {

                notification:{
                    title: "Friend Request",
                    body: "you have received a new friend request",
                    icon: "default"
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
                        .then(response =>{
                            console.log('This was the notification feature.');
                        });
        });
    });
```

> Blockquote

6- Then I deployed using `firebase deploy` and waited 30 seconds

7- I installed the application on 2 devices and cleaned the database. 
In the end, nothing is showing in the functions section in firebase

Comment: The first step is to accept and embrace the fact that probably you *didn't* do everything right, or else it'd be working.

Comment: I followed this steps multiple times and didn't work and watched a lot of videos that made the same steps

Comment: ok, then, uh what do you want from us? If your code and methods are perfect, are you suggesting there is a problem with *firebase*. If you suspect a bug, then file a bug report with the appropriate entity. However, you'll need more detailed proof that the error is on their end before doing so.

Comment: Which version of Cloud Functions for Firebase are you using. It seems you use an old syntax, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff. You should check in your package.json file and confirm that this syntax is in line with your version. (In any case it would be a good idea to migrate to a recent CF version)

Comment: @SherylHohman I'am using firebase cloud messaging version 11.8.0

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, see above. OP meant to direct his comment to you.

Comment: Piggy backing Renaud Tarnec's comment, what version of firebase were your tutorials using? If they didn't state, you can check the year the tutorial was published, then Google firebase version release dates. The tutorial must address *some version* earlier than that date. Alternatively, Google for tutorials specific to your current version. Or on Google page, click `tools`, set the date to sometime after your version's release date, and search tutorials. Compare instructions. Also consider posting on a Firebase Forum. They likely might be a better match for this question.

Comment: @KaremMohamed I mean the version of Cloud Functions, not Cloud Messaging. The best is that you share the content of the entire `package.json` file that you'll find with the `index.js` file.

Comment: sorry It's my first time but how

Comment: Click in the "edit" link at the bottom of your question and add the content of the `package.json` file to your question. At the bottom for example.

Comment: I don't have cloud function implemented in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "firebase deploy --only functions" this command?

Comment: @KaremMohamed in what way did it "not work"? Please include details as to exactly what did or did not happen vs what you expected to happen. Please review "How to Ask" and other common topics on the Help section is this website.

Comment: Do u have a decent internet connection?